# Display only few menu from list and last menus under a navigation icon

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have a menu list can have more than 7 menus. But I want to display 7 in menu bar and extra menu under a toggle button which displayed in right of menu. I don't want to do this by adding a child of last menu.

Comment: wht u tried ????????? put some codessss

Comment: Show some code for help.

Comment: I tried it using firebug. I want to display 25*25 box and li when hovering the box. But when I tak the hover on li's it doesn't remain on screen. I put the last 3 <li> in a <ul> in firebug. But What I mean to asks is if there is any jquery library or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your code and what you've tried but something like this should get your started:

**EDIT:** Updated Code

```
function toggleMenus($) {
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
        $lastItem = $menu.find('li:eq(4)'), // how many to display, from 0.
        $targets = $menu.find('li:gt(' + $lastItem.index() + ')'), //get the rest
        $toggler = $('<li class="toggler"><span>More Menu Items +</span></li>'),
        $targetBox = $('<div id="more-menu"></div>');

    $targets.appendTo($targetBox); // fill the overflow box.
    $lastItem.addClass('moremenu');     

    // Insert the toggler at the last position    
    $toggler.insertAfter($lastItem)
        .on('click', 'span', function () { // toggle the overflow box on click
        $targetBox.toggleClass('active');
    })
        .css('position', 'relative') // for absolute positioning of the target box
    .append($targetBox); // attach the overflow box


}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    toggleMenus($);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/bB2rv/3/

Comment: Yes absolutely right. Any way to add class to the last li. like "moremenu".

Comment: And I am using bootstrap theme framework. So I don't want this to add on small screen or when resize screen.

Comment: thanks very much. I will handle the remaining with media queries css. :)